# Securing AJAX & SSL

Tags: ajax, ssl, https

I've been trying to determine whether I can implement AJAX & SSL, so this may be a dumb question, but hoping that someone can confirm / refute my current limited understanding of it...

If I have a page: https://mysite.com/page1 that includes a javascript src file which passes data via ajax to https://mysite.com/process.php and spits back output, it won't be a problem, right, and everything will remain under SSL?  It's only a problem if I start mixing protocols?  Like if I have a non-SSL page make AJAX calls to an SSL page, or vice versa?

I've been searching for AJAX & SSL, but most of the results thus far have been about workarounds for cross domain / cross protocol issues, so I'm just hoping to gain some clarification here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything will be fine. You will have no problems with everything in the same site.