# Call SOAP service with client certificate from Angular

Tags: angular, security, ssl, soap, x509certificate

I want to call to SOAP service which is protected by X509 certificate directly from Angular.
Any client needs to authenticate through a valid certificate
installed in a local trust store.

Can I do this after installing the certificate (https://www.globalsign.com/en-sg/blog/installing-certificates-onto-android-devices/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear in your question if you need to sign a SOAP message or configure a SSL connection with client authentication. **It is not possible in either case.**

- An SSL authentication with client certificates can not be done directly from an AJAX request. See [Using jQuery's ajax() function with an SSL client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567776/using-jquerys-ajax-function-with-an-ssl-client-certificate)
- A certificate from the browser keystore can not be used to sign a message from JavaScript. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208561/6371459

You will need to call an intermediate server that is responsible for making the soap call